# variable is not getting set to AMER

Tags: shell

Below is the code :

```
if [ "$p_geo_code" = S America ]; then   
'$p_geo_code'=AMER; fi
```

Unable to get the value as AMER instead getting 'S America'.
can you let me know where i am going wrong,

Comment: The `$` is not part of the variable name, like in Perl. It's essentially an operator that produces the value of a parameter given its name.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison with a multi-word string should be in quotes otherwise the shell won't know what you're asking it to compare, and variable assignment does not use the `$` symbol, just the variable name:

```
if [ "$p_geo_code" = "S America" ]; then
    p_geo_code=AMER
fi
```